# vscode's semantic token coloring not working for strings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have these lines in the **settings.json**:

```
  "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
          "string": { "foreground": "#ff0000" }, // doesn't work
          "*.declaration": { "bold": true }, // works
        }
  },
```

Notice there are two rules in there, but although the second one works, the first one (rule for coloring the "string"s) doesn't:

[image]

Now, according to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#semantic-token-classification) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/semantic-tokens-sample/sample/sample.semanticLanguage), the "string" token does exist and so it should work (unless I'm missing something).

Another guess is that maybe a theme is getting in the way, but I uninstalled all the non-default themes and yet the result is the same(declarations are bolded while strings are not colored).

P.S: I've not used the textmate rules because when I try token inspection, it suggests so many tokens for everything in a more detailed manner but I don't want to write so many rules, when what I want is just simply a rule to color ALL the strings.

**Edit:** I decided to give the Textmate way a try as well, the scope for strings would be `string.quoted.double`, but this time, it can't be mixed with the previous rule! So now the colorizing rule works, while the styling doesn't:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "enabled": true,
      "rules": {
        "*.declaration": { "bold": true }, // doesn't work
      },
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "string.quoted.double",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#ff0000", // works
            },
        }
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, using both textmate and the semantic customization, and writing the two rules "separately" seems to work(The textmate method is the older (original) tokenization method of the visual studio code, while the semantic one was added recently):

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "string.quoted.double",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#8b7a69"
            }
        }
    ]
  },
  "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
          "*.declaration": { "bold": true },
        }
  },
```